# Which SDK to use for Sony Ericsson w100?

Tags: mobile, sdk, sony

I want to create my personal calendar app for sony ericsson w100, but I don't know which of [those SDK](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/downloads?cc=gb&lc=en) is better for that? (there's even Symbiam SDK!? I thought it was just for Nokia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java ME SDK is probably your only option. This is a pretty primitive phone, but it should handle JavaME OK.